# wxPython - Optional Text Boxes

Tags: python, wxpython

How can I add a

> TextCtrl

area that will allow input only if a checkbox is ticked?  Otherwise the TextCtrl area will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Bind an event handler for the checkbox widget that will call the textctrl's Enable method, passing True or False based on the status of the checkbox.